# Is there any OR condition in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I am making a userscript for greasemonkey that changes the links within `<a>` to some other site links. Currently it is set to fire up if user press **~** (tilde perhaps) on the keyboard. I also want it to work when document is `ready`. How can I set up two conditions?

- if document is ready

or

- User press ~ key

run the jquery function (change the url).

Here is my code

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==96){
        $('a').each(function(){
            this.href = this.href.replace('youtube.com/watch?v=', 'ytpak.com/?component=video&task=view&id=');
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean on document ready? Run it right when the page loads?

Comment: What about the two different event handlers pointing to a common function?

Comment: Yes. when page loads $(document).ready

Comment: if you had it triggered on both document ready and keypress document ready would override the keypress function because it would have triggered the function before the key is pressed.

Comment: Previously I was using the `(document).ready` only. I tested it on Google, but when I reach the 2nd page or any other page on Google, the URL wont change anymore. So I wanted to allow the users to use ~ key if it is not working automatically.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, because why would you fire up something when the page is loaded and do exactly the same when the key is pressed? There won't be anything to get done at the second moment. But... This would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/pX676/1/

Comment: I have mentioned the problem with Google search

Comment: On other sites it working just fine. I think that it has something to do with the page refresh scheme used by Google. Because on first page this script changed the URL successfully

Comment: I've deleted my previous comments because I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Tip: Use `keydown` instead of `keypress` for better browser compatibility. This is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pX676/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally got what do you want.

I still believe it's a bit pointless, because your script will run when the page is loaded and change the links. There won't be anything else to be done when the user press the key.

But, this should do the trick:

```
// A common function to be called by both event handlers.
function doMyStuff(e) {    
    // When the page is loaded, you won't have a parameter so
    // you check for undefined.
    if (typeof e == "undefined" || e.keyCode == 96) {
        $('a').each(function() {
            this.href = this.href.replace('youtube.com/watch?v=', 'ytpak.com/?component=video&task=view&id=');
        }); 
    }
}

$(function () {
    // On document ready.
    console.log('Document loaded');
    doMyStuff();

    // Use keydown for better browser compatibility.
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log('Key pressed');
        doMyStuff(e);
    });        
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pX676/3/) Check on your browser console for the log messages (press F12).

Comment: Made some changes to it and finally got what I was looking for. Thanks for your time.